# How to Center Align ng-Table Header?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

All , 
 I am using ng-table for the Grid. I am using following code snippet to set the  column .

```html
<td data-title="'Access ID'" sortable="'accessID'" style="width:120px" class="text-center">{{people.accessID}}</td>
```

[image]

But I am not able to center align the Column Header but column data.

Here is the source code snippet for Access ID Header.

```html
<th ng-repeat="column in $columns" ng-class="{ 'sortable': parse(column.sortable), 'sort-asc': params.sorting()[parse(column.sortable)]=='asc', 'sort-desc': params.sorting()[parse(column.sortable)]=='desc' }" ng-click="sortBy(column, $event)" ng-show="column.show(this)" ng-init="template=column.headerTemplateURL(this)" class="header  sortable"> <!-- ngIf: !template --><div ng-if="!template" ng-show="!template" ng-bind="parse(column.title)" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Access ID</div><!-- end ngIf: !template --> <!-- ngIf: template --> </th>
```

Question is , How to center align the Header for a particular column in ng-table?

Comment: text-align center not working?

Comment: @Gokul: Did you find solution to your program?

Answer (score 12):

The answer submitted by @OpenUserX03 is almost perfect, except you have to wrap the class name in single quotes, like so:

```
<td data-title="'Access ID'" sortable="'accessID'" style="width:120px" class="text-center" header-class="'text-center'">{{people.accessID}}</td>
```

Comment: It likely depends on the version of the library you're using. The version that we have (oddly enough not included in the JS) does not support the expression form of `headerClass`; @OpenUserX03's answer works for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `header-class` attribute to set the class for - you guessed it - the header.

```
<td data-title="'Access ID'" sortable="'accessID'" style="width:120px" class="text-center" header-class="text-center">{{people.accessID}}</td>
```

Comment: For me, the currect syntax which worked was: header-class=" 'text-center' ",  Not: header-class="text-center"

Answer (score 3):

i used to have the same issue how to align left my ng-table headers.
on the documentation of ng-table it does not say anything nor at the examples.

you have two ways to do this the fast and the more 'professional'

**fast way:**

open files **ng-table/dist/ng-table.css and ng-table.min.css**, according on which css file you use.
on the first line it manages the header,

```
.ng-table th {
  text-align: center;/*just change that parameter to left/right*/
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

**'professional' way:** create a custom style and add it to your website css file ,like this :

```
.table thead th {
  text-align: left;/*change that parameter to left/right*/
}
```

Hope helps, good luck.

Answer (score 3):

To anyone who still has this issue, also OP, since he has not yet accepted an answer, this is how I do it. in your css (any .css)

```
table[ng-table] th {
  text-align: left;
  border-top: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Fix for ngTable**

For those seeing this a year later. None of the above solutions worked for me. I added this to a custom css file:

```
.ng-table th {
   text-align: center !important;
}
```

Which centered the content in the header (see images)

**From this:**

[image: left]

**To this:**

[image: center]

Answer (score 0):

```
table .text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BrTzg/411/

Comment: He is asking specifically about column headers using ng-table.  Your example works because it isn't using ng-table.

Comment: add the headers are not centered in the jsFiddle